# Command 'source' do not work in script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, source

1. In the command line it's working well:

   ```
   $ . /home/gk/venv36/bin/activate
   ```
2. The same command in the script file is not working. The file has 744 modes. All echo-commands before and after `. /home/gk/venv36/bin/activate`
   are working.

Is something wrong?

Here is the script file:

```
$ #! /bin/bash
$ echo "Jupyter notebook running..."
$ . /home/gk/venv36/bin/activate
$ jupyter notebook
```

Comment: I don't see "command source" anywhere.

Comment: @dessert You added a space after the dot :-)

Comment: What does the activate script do?  What is the output that you are expecting?

Comment: Look at `bash -x /home/gk/venv36/bin/activate`

Comment: Why does your script have a dollar sign at the start of each line?

Comment: @Pilot6 The dot command `.` is the exact same as `source`